# Static field initialization Order in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, clr

I came across **[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-field-initialization)** link and found the below snippet. I was curious to try the snippet to get the uncertain output.

*The following snippet:*

```
using System;
class Test
{
   static void Main() 
   {  // Breakpoint here is skipped and control goes to Class B then Class A
      // Why control is always going to Class B first?
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", B.Y, A.X);
   }
   public static int F(string s) {
      Console.WriteLine(s);
      return 1;
   }
}
class A
{       // 
   public static int X = Test.F("Init A");
}
class B
{       // Debugging always starts here.
   public static int Y = Test.F("Init B");
}
```

might produce either the output:

> Init A
>
> Init B
>
> 1 1

or the output:

> Init B
>
> Init A
>
> 1 1

However, for some reason, I am always getting the 2nd output. No matter how many times I run / rebuild / build.

**Can someone please explain me:**

1. Why only Class B is getting executed first? If I reverse the call as
   **'A.X, B.Y'**, then only Class A gets executed first.
2. How can I simulate the uncertain behavior?

Comment: You're unlikely to see variation if you're just running on the same machine against the same CLR. The uncertainty and flexibility are there to allow e.g. different implementations of the JIT compiler.

Comment: It would not surprise me if the order of execution were related to the order that is required by the code - why initialise something if it is not required. If you call with "B.Y, B.Y" - then I would expect that A.X is not initialised.

Comment: Fully reading your link I see the wording is this : _"Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class."_ and later _"they are only constrained to occur before the references to those fields"_. So really all it is saying is that the initialisation must be done prior to first use & it is up to the implementation to decide when - which is not the same as saying the behaviour is uncertain & could happen in either order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why only Class B is getting executed first?

The specification is saying that both outputs are valid. But a specific combination of a compiler and runtime (e.g. the compiler for C# 7.0 running on .Net Framework 4.7) can decide to be more strict and behave consistently.

It seems the combination you're using decides to first initialize static fields of the class that is used first, and doing that is acceptable according to the specification.

> How can I simulate the uncertain behavior?

Again, the specification does not require any uncertainty.

If you really wanted to make it behave that way, you could modify an existing .Net runtime (like CoreCLR, Mono or [DotNetAnywhere](https://github.com/chrisdunelm/DotNetAnywhere)), to find all the possible orders of initialization and then choose one at random.